# Automating Ansible VMware with lookup dig

Tags: templates, ansible, vmware, esxi

I'm currently trying to further automate VM automation by not having to include the IP address in the variables file. I found nslookup module with dig, but feel I'm going about this the wrong way, for example here is variables file which is read upon creation for details:

```
# VMware Launch Variables

# If this is a test deployment you must ensure the vm is terminated after use.
vmname: agent5

esxi_datacenter: Datacenter
esxi_cluster: Cluster
esxi_datastore: ds1 # Do not change value.
esxi_template: template-v2
esxi_folder: agents # Folder must be pre-created

# Static IP Addresses
esxi_static_ip: "{{ lookup('dig', '{{ vmname }}.example.com.') }}"
esxi_netmask: 255.255.252.0
esxi_gateway: 10.0.0.1
```

What I was hoping to do with these was just to have the "esxi_static_ip" but pulled on the fly from a lookup with dig. This, however, in its current state does not work.

What is happening is either the VM launches without an ipv4 address or more often it fails with the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create a virtual machine : A specified parameter was not correct: spec.nicSettingMap.adapter.ip.ipAddress"}
```

I get the IP and pass it along, which works when I hard code the esxi_static_ip: in my vmware-lanch-vars.yml file. However, if I use (including the examples) it fails.

The newvm is registered when I run my vmware_guest playbook.

```
- name: Make virtual machine IP persistant
  set_fact:
    newvm_ip_address: '{{ newvm.instance.ipv4 }}'

- name: Add host to in memory inventory
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ newvm_ip_address }}"
    groups: just_created
    newvm_ip_address: "{{ newvm.instance.ipv4 }}"
```

When I run with -vvvv I can see no IP is being attached:

```
    "networks": [
        {
            "device_type": "vmxnet3",
            "gateway": "0.0.0.01",
            "ip": "",
            "name": "Network",
            "netmask": "255.255.252.0",
            "type": "static"
        }
    ],
```

**UPDATE 3**

When I created a simple playbook it works, just not when I put it into my regular flow, this below works:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vmname: "apim-sb-ng1-agent2"
    vm_dig_fqdn: "{{ vmname }}.example.com."
    esxi_static_ip: "{{ lookup('dig', vm_dig_fqdn) }}"

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ esxi_static_ip }}"
```

Comment: Please give an accurate definition of "does not work".

Comment: My apologies for the lack of that information. I've added what happens, including using the below examples. My hope was that I would, as all vm's being launched were static IP that this would be the easiest method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the first problem your are facing (see my comment above), but your jinja2 template expression is wrong.

You cannot use jinja2 expression expansion while already inside a jinja2 expression expansion.

In this case, you have to concatenate your variable and string with the `+` operator:

```yaml
esxi_static_ip: "{{ lookup('dig', vmname + '.example.com.') }}"
```

If your prefer to use jinja2 expansion everywhere, you can separate this in different variables, e.g.:

```yaml
vm_dig_fqdn: "{{ vmname }}.example.com."
esxi_static_ip: "{{ lookup('dig', vm_dig_fqdn) }}"
```

Comment: I've updated my above example to show how I'm doing it. As stated if I hard code the IP in esxi_static_ip it creates the "instance.ipv4" found in get_facts and I pass that along. If I try dynamic it must not be.

Comment: In the end, it looks like a typo on my side, this works now with your second example.

Thank you very much.